Given a vector v and fn f, how do I generate the matrix {v, f(v), f(f(v)), ... f^k(v)}?
I have a vector x and a function f. I need to generate the matrix whose first column is v, second column is f(v), and so on up to the final column f^k(v).  In a functional language I could use an unfold operation. I've had a look at the purrr cheatsheet, but I can't spot any analogue.
If you need a concrete example, take v = c(1:100) and f = function(x){return (2*x)} -- but please don't exploit the fact that f^k happens to have a nice closed form in this case.

there's probably a short recursive solution if you define your own recursion

@qwr I don't have a good model of what's happening under the hood in R and am worried about efficiency. E.g. I don't want to end up allocating k matrices and doing O(k^2) copying.

Is this a generalization of Vandermonde matrices?

what's wrong with a for loop? I've found functional code can be a lot slower in R when it's not optimized for a particular task. especially purrr.

@qwr I've been reading since posting the q and come to the same conclusion. I think it was just that I'm new to R and I'd never seen a for loop in R code!  (Also, not Vandermonde. Something like simulating a markov chain.)

Most people use R to manipulate dataframes (akin to relational data model). General matrix stuff is more numpy's strong suit.

Are you looking for something like:
v = c(1:100)  
f = function(x){return (2*x)}

df <- data.frame(v)

for( i in 1:5) {
   df[,(i+1)] <- f(df[,i])
}


Possibly. I don't understand the memory model there. What's happening under the hood when you keep adding more columns to v?

I really don't know. May not be a concern, unless v is very long or k is large.  If you are concern with creation and deletion of multiple matrices, then just preallocate the final size up front.

I'd write it as pre-allocating the C / FORTRAN way because it doesn't make sense to dynamically grow an object you know the final size of.

Pre-allocating a matrix and filling it is about 10x faster, although the slower version still only takes about 0.1 seconds to construct a 1000x100 matrix ... using Reduce() gains additional factor of 2x speed. Trying to use the string-construction method hits an "evaluation nested too deeply" error.
f <- function(x) {return (2*x)} 
f1 <- function(n1 = 1000, n2 = 1000) {
    df <- data.frame(seq.int(n1))
    for (i in 1:(n2-1)) {
        df[,(i+1)] <- f(df[,i])
    }
    df <- as.matrix(df)
    dimnames(df) <- NULL
    df
}

f2 <- function(n1= 1000, n2 = 1000) {
    df <- matrix(nrow=n1, ncol = n2)
    df[,1] <- seq.int(n1)
    for (i in 1:(n2-1)) {
        df[,(i+1)] <- f(df[,i])
    }
    df
}

f3 <- function(n1 = 1000, n2 = 1000) { 
    v <- seq.int(n1)
   do.call(cbind, Reduce(\(x, y) f(x), rep(list(v), n2), 
                         accumulate = TRUE)) 
}

bench:mark(f1(), f2(), f3() )  
expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 f1()       126.75ms 126.81ms      7.89        NA     3.94     2     1
2 f2()         8.14ms   8.93ms    107.          NA    19.5     33     6
3 f3()         3.67ms   3.98ms    221.          NA    21.2     73     7

(I think the slow method would be much slower if you were growing the data frame rowwise rather than columnwise ...)

You could use Reduce like below
v <- 1:10
k <- 5
f <- \(x) 2 * x
do.call(cbind, Reduce(\(x, y) f(x), rep(list(v), 5), accumulate = TRUE))

which gives result
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    2    4    8   16
 [2,]    2    4    8   16   32
 [3,]    3    6   12   24   48
 [4,]    4    8   16   32   64
 [5,]    5   10   20   40   80
 [6,]    6   12   24   48   96
 [7,]    7   14   28   56  112
 [8,]    8   16   32   64  128
 [9,]    9   18   36   72  144
[10,]   10   20   40   80  160


@BenBolker aha, you are right! I forgot to cbind them

This is also the fastest (so far) FWIW

@BenBolker wow, it’s out of my expectations, glad to see that speed

Another approach, growing the function formula instead of the memory object (see R-Inferno p. 12):

this function first generates a string, containing k calls to function f, chained with the pipe operator |>, then parses the string and evaluates it on x:


    raise_f <- \(f, k, x) {
      parse(text = paste('x |> ',
                         sprintf('(%s)()',  paste(deparse(f), collapse = ' ')) |> 
                rep(k) |> paste(collapse = ' |> ')
      )
      ) |> eval()
    }



try the function on a length-5 vector, raise f from 1 to 3, cbind resulting vectors into matrix:


    f <- \(x) 2 * x
    k <- 3
    init <- 1:5
    
    do.call(cbind, Map(1:3, f = \(k) raise_f(f, k, 1:5)))


output:

    ##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
    ## [1,]    2    4    8
    ## [2,]    4    8   16
    ## [3,]    6   12   24
    ## [4,]    8   16   32
    ## [5,]   10   20   40


Performance comparison with looping a matrix:

    library(microbenchmark)
    
    microbenchmark(
      loop_a_matrix = for( i in 1:5) {df[,(i+1)] <- f(df[,i])},
      grow_a_formula = do.call(cbind, Map(1:5, f = \(k) raise_f(f, k, 1:100)))
    )
    
    ## Unit: microseconds
    ##            expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval cld
    ##   loop_a_matrix 5481.6 6350.55 7254.535 7012.95 7999.2 12083.5   100  a 
    ##  grow_a_formula  919.1 1044.00 1335.874 1219.80 1419.6  3817.9   100   b



This wins points for cleverness but "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question" (Thomas Lumley 2005, fortunes::fortune("If the answer is parse"))

Gotta re-read (and fully grasp) advanced R one day :-)

We have functional programming precisely so we don't have to do string function jank like this!

@qwr : any hints on constructing a recursive expression like f(f(x)) from f (not making f a recursive function)?

I would use a recursive function with cbind that builds it up column by column, either reading the last column made or passing it in as an argument. But this won't be as efficient as the simple for loop solution.
